# isSelected returns false and isChecked shows compilation error

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

```
let checkBoxXpath = accessPolicyPage.listCheckBoxXpathS + i + accessPolicyPage.listCheckBoxXpathE;
//element(by.xpath(checkBoxXpath)).click();
expect(element(by.xpath(checkBoxXpath)).isSelected()).toBeTruthy();
```

in the above code isSelected returns false and if I replace it by isChecked, it shows error as "property 'ischecked' not found on ElementFinder"

How I can overcome this

Comment: that's because that element is not there in DOM.

Comment: element is there, I can access it by "click()"

Comment: I think you are using protractor... if so, there is no definition given for isChecked... as you can refer to -  http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isSelected

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called isChecked in Protractor. You can do this by using isSelected.

```
webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isSelected = function() {
  return this.schedule_(
      new webdriver.Command(webdriver.CommandName.IS_ELEMENT_SELECTED),
      'WebElement.isSelected()');
};
```

Refer [this](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isSelected) to more information. Hope this helps. :)