# isChecked caused a compilation error in Protractor

Tags: checkbox, protractor

I'm kind of new to Protractor. I'm trying to write a automation script using protractor.

I have a check box in my angular js application.

I searched everywhere to find a method to check whether the check box is checked or not.

Can someone tell me how to do that?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you searched every where? Because, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004599/isselected-returns-false-and-ischecked-shows-compilation-error/36006203#36006203) has the answer for your question.

There is nothing called isChecked in Protractor. You can do this by using isSelected.

```
webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isSelected = function() {
  return this.schedule_(
      new webdriver.Command(webdriver.CommandName.IS_ELEMENT_SELECTED),
      'WebElement.isSelected()');
};
```

Refer [this](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isSelected) documentation.

Hope this helps. :)