# How do I implement isChecked in Protractor

Tags: protractor, ischecked

I'm new to protractor and I need to know how to write a protractor script to check whether a check box is checked or not. I searched every where to find is there anything called isChecked and I couldn't find.

Please help.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004599/isselected-returns-false-and-ischecked-shows-compilation-error/36006203#36006203). There is nothing called `isChecked`in Protractor.

You can use `isSelect`to do the same thing.

```
webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isSelected = function() {
  return this.schedule_(
      new webdriver.Command(webdriver.CommandName.IS_ELEMENT_SELECTED),
      'WebElement.isSelected()');
};
```

Hope my answer helps you. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :)